# Error creating a database with Chef using database cookbook

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm provisioning a Vagrant `bento/centos6.7` box using `chef_solo` provisioner. I'm using `berkshelf-plugin` for the cookbook dependencies.

My project folder looks like this:

```
|── Vagrantfile
|── cookbooks
    └── my_cookbook
        |── Berksfile
        |── metadata.rb
...
```

Inside my `Vagrantfile` (which is the default for `bento/centos6.7` plus the following config)

```
config.berkshelf.enabled = true
config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = "cookbooks/my_cookbook/Berksfile"

config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe "my_cookbook"
end
```

In my `metadata.rb`

```
depends 'mysql2_chef_gem', '~> 1.1'
depends 'database', '~> 5.1'
```

When I provision my vagrant machine, I get the following error:

```
Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_database[my_database]'

Mysql2::Error
-------------
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110
```

**PS:** it works perfectly on `bento/centos7.2`

**EDIT**: Here is the database creation part:

```
# Install the MySQL client
mysql_client 'default' do
  action :create
end

# Configure the MySQL service
mysql_service 'default' do
  initial_root_password node['webserver']['database']['root_password']
  action [:create, :start]
end

# Install the mysql2 Ruby gem
mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do
  action :install
end

mysql_database node['webserver']['database']['db_name'] do
  connection(
    :host     => node['webserver']['database']['host'],
    :username => node['webserver']['database']['root_username'],
    :password => node['webserver']['database']['root_password']
   )
  action :create
end
```

**EDIT 2:** It doesn't really work on `bento/centos7.2`. It doesn't crash, but MySQL seems to be dead and running `sudo systemctl start mysqld` hangs.

Comment: Could you paste here the part of the recipe that has the `mysql_database` resource?

Comment: @zuazo I updated my question providing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was over suggestion by the fact that I was using many new things (I'm also new to Chef) so I thought the problem came from a different source (vagrant, bad bersfile integration, something else).

Turns out I just didn't [read the docs](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql#connecting-with-the-mysql-cli-command) which clearly states:

> Logging into the machine and typing mysql with no extra arguments will fail. You need to explicitly connect over the socket with mysql -S /var/run/mysql-foo/mysqld.sock, or over the network with mysql -h 127.0.0.1